# Symfony2 Unable to find the controller for path

Tags: php, symfony, routes

All of my research on this problem lead me to nothing :

I still have this error : *Unable to find the controller for path "/blog/1". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?*, every time with this route for BlogBundle

```
blog_index:
    path:    /{page}
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  "\d*"
        _method:  GET

blog_see:
    path:    /article/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:voir }
    requirements:
        id:  "\d+"
        _method:  GET

blog_add:
    path:    /add
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:ajouter }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST

blog_update:
    path:    /update/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:modifier }
    requirements:
        id:  "\d+"
        _method:  GET

blog_delete:
    path:    /delete/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:supprimer }
    requirements:
        id:  "\d+"
        _method:  GET
```

And here is the app one :

```
default:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /

path:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /blog
```

Comment: Try to use `page:  \d+` for your `blog_index` route instead of `page:  "\d*"`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but doesn't work. It seems like my cache:clear goes in infinite loop and crash.

Comment: So, `rm -rf app/cache/*` ; ) And please remove `"` characters from your patterns: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements

Comment: Done but doesn't work either (I use http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/blog/1)

Comment: I'm wrong... Do you have controller with name `Blog` in in your bundle `PathBlogBundle`? This controller should be in `/src/Path/BlogBundle/Controllers/BlogController.php` and should have `indexAction` method.

Comment: you should have a `BlogController.php` in your `PathBlogBundle` with a `indexAction($page)` function.  If you don't have these exact files/code, you will get this error

Comment: He's named BlogController do I have to put BundleController at the end ? And I have and indexAction method.

Comment: also, is your `routing.yml` file located in the correct place? What if you tried to request `localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/1`, what happens?

Comment: It returns No route found for "GET /1"

I'm completly lost ...

Comment: Convention is: `AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show`, where `AcmeBlogBundle` - your bundle name `Blog` - your controller name (without `Controller` in name) `show` - method name (without Action in name). http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-in-action

Comment: Ok so controller name is correct. Maybe it's because it's not an Acme bundle ?

Comment: It seems that this is definitely an issue with how your controller is named/configured.  Ensure you have `BlogController.php` in your `Controller` directory, and this file should contain a class, like so: `class BlogController extends Controller`, and you should have a `public function indexAction($page)` method defined. can you verify this?

Comment: I've just verified twice it's exactly what I have here ;(

Comment: I just realized that your main routing.yml file is importing the same file twice.  once with a `/` prefix, and once with the `/blog` prefix.  Can you comment out the default route import with the `/` prefix? It doesn't make sense to import the same file twice, because your route names will be duplicated and could cause collisions.

Comment: I've done that because I don't have any route for / yet without it, but ok I'll delete these line.

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: Sure, [here](http://pastebin.com/NN2ySQpk) it is

Comment: what happens if you try to access `localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/blog/add`? Are you sent to the correct page?

Comment: No, same kind of error

Comment: Then this leads me to believe that your routing must not be setup correctly. I will post an answer to show you what to try for testing

Comment: @Totem and what about environments? Are your sure that you've configured routing for correct env? I mean that maybe you configured routing for `prod` and try to call it for `dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely lies in the app/config/config.yml file. You seem to be having two different configurations pointing to the same resource instead of one.

```
default:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /

DagomaBlogBundle:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /blog
```

Symfony looks at the first configuration, that is

```
default:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /
```

try deleting the configuration with prefix path / and refresh.

Comment: can you put the blog_index config at the end of the file and refresh?

Comment: looking at saheel's answer, what does this url give you on the browser?  localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/blog/blog/1

Answer (score 0):

In `app/config/routing.yml` comment out the imported routing files(for testing).  Add this:

```
blog_index:
    path:    /blog/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: PathBlogBundle:Blog:index, page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page:  \d+
        _method:  GET
```

If this works, then you know that the problem lies with how you are importing the yml files.  If this doesn't work, then there must be a deeper issue somewhere.

UPDATE:

add the following in `app/config/routing.yml`

```
path:
    resource: "@PathBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:    /blog
```

Comment: You must be importing the routing.yml file wrong.  can you tell me the absolute path of the routing file that you want to import? I can tell you how to import it then.

Comment: Folder of imported routing : /var/www/Symfony/src/Path/BlogBundle/Resources/config

Comment: and what is the name of the yml file? is it `routing.yml`, or something else?

Comment: interesting, then your import should be working.  Regardless, leave everything in `app/config/routing.yml` commented out, and add just the import that I add to my answer(just for testing).  let's see if it will work if it is the only thing in the file.

Comment: Arf doesn't work if I reques blog/article/1 or blog/add

Comment: hmm, on the command line can you run this command: `php app/console router:debug` and does it list the routes that are included in your imported yml file?

Comment: Yes :  blog_index               GET    ANY    ANY  /blog/{page}                      
 blog_see                 GET    ANY    ANY  /blog/article/{id}                
 blog_add                 GET    ANY    ANY  /blog/add                         
 blog_update              GET    ANY    ANY  /blog/update/{id}                 
 blog_delete              GET    ANY    ANY  /blog/delete/{id}

Comment: ok, then run `php app/console router:debug blog_index` and see if it gives any hints to why it won't work

Comment: ok, this is my last idea, run `php app/console router:match /blog/1` this should tell you if this url matches a route.

Comment: Thank you for your time Sehael; it is much appreciated. I think I'm lost so I'll make a fresh new project. I miss something ...

Comment: if that last command doesn't match anything, try removing the `requirements` part of your routes.  In theory, that should match if there are no restrictions

Comment: hmm, that is strange indeed. I am out of ideas

Comment: It works but my twig view isn't working well, I've some html tags (body, html and head).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing extra spaces near {} in route.